# Reactjs: handleNames functions automatically post data via Reactjs axios as page load

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs: **handleNames()** functions automatically post data via Reactjs axios as page load.

Am supposed to post each persons name when I click on **Post-Names** button.

but here the
**handleNames()** functions seems to automatically post data via axios as page load.

**when I check my console i can 
see over 3000 request/call per seconds automatically made to the axio API via handleNames()** without me clicking on the Post-Name button.

Please any solution on this as I want to 
only post to the axios when I click on Post Name button

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: [], loading: false
  }

    this.handleNames = this.handleNames.bind(this);
}


componentDidMount() {


 this.setState({
           data: 
[{"id":"1","name":"Tony","gender":"male"},
{"id":"2","name":"Mark","gender":"male"},
{"id":"3","name":"Joy","gender":"female"}]


        });
}


 handleNames(name) {

const data1 = {
      name: name
    };
axios.get("http://localhost/postname.php", {data1})

           .then(response => {
             this.setState({data: response.data});

console.log(this.state.data);

           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
           });
}

render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <label>


<ul>
            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {person.name} - {person.gender} 


<br />

<input type="button" value="Post-Names"   onClick={this.handleNames(person.name)}  />

              </li>
            ))}

          </ul>

           </label>


      </span>
   );    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input `onClick` handler, you're passing and evaluating the function, that's the reason it is posting automatically because it is being call on render. Click handlers should receive functions, so you could try something like this:

```
<input 
    type="button"
    value="Post-Names"
    onClick={() => this.handleNames(person.name)}
/>
```

Or make the handleNames method something like this:

```
handleNames = (name) = () => {...}
```

Hope it solves the problem, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are immediately invoking your handler function here:

```
onClick={this.handleNames(person.name)}
```

You should use it with an `onClick` callback.

```
onClick={() => this.handleNames(person.name)}
```